# Issue binding to MVXSpinner after upgrading to Mvvmcross v4.0.0-beta3

Tags: binding, mvvmcross

I just updated all of my Mvvmcross libraries to version 4.0.0-beta3 and it looks like it may have broken the binding of the MVXSpinner.

I get the following message in the output:

MvxBind:Warning:  5.40 Failed to create target binding for binding SelectedItem for SelectedColor

Here is the xml:

```
<MvxSpinner
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/colorSpinner"
               android:spinnerMode="dropdown"                 
               android:layout_below="@id/maintoolbar"
               local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ColorList; SelectedItem SelectedColor" />
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
    public HomeViewModel(IKrizzmaService service, IMvxMessenger messenger)
        :base(service, messenger)
    {
        SelectedColor = "Blue";
    }

    private static string[] _colorList = { "Yellow", "Brown", "White", "Blue", "Orange", "Red", "Green", "Purple" };
    public string[] ColorList
    {
        get { return _colorList; }
    }

    private string _selectedColor;
    public string SelectedColor
    {
        get { return _selectedColor; }
        set
        {
            _selectedColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedColor);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version did you come from? There where some changes from 3.5.1 to 4.0 which might be of effect on this.

Comment: Hmm, should work. One thing i am not sure about is if the string[] you use works correctly with the spinner. Maybe try to switch to `List`?

Comment: Okay I'll take another look.  I posted this example, but I also tried the example from here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid.  The list is populated, but the first item is selected, not "Blue" which I indicated as selected.

Comment: @Martijn00, I have recreated the issue in a new solution using the MvxSpinner example from github.  I started with beta2 and then beta3 and both worked.  I then started adding packages that I am using in my main project.  The binding failed as above after adding the Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.AppCompat package and inheriting from MvxAppCompatActivity in my view.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then. Could you make an issue in the repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories` from your `Setup.cs`'s `FillTargetFactories()`