# Xamarin Android Spinner Binding Selection not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am able to bind the array `_limitQuickPosts` to my spinner. But I am having difficulties figuring out how to bind the Selected to my `_selectedLimitQuickPosts`. No matter what I do I can't get it to make the Selected value be "Show last 200 Posts".

Core ViewModel:

```
private string[] _limitQuickPosts = new string[4]
{
    "Show last 25 Posts",
    "Show last 50 Posts",
    "Show last 100 Posts",
    "Show last 200 Posts"
};
public string[] LimitQuickPosts 
{
    get { return _limitQuickPosts; }
    set { _limitQuickPosts = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => LimitQuickPosts); }
}

private string _selectedLimitQuickPosts = "Show last 200 Posts";
public string SelectedLimitQuickPosts 
{
    get { return _selectedLimitQuickPosts; }
    set { _selectedLimitQuickPosts = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedLimitQuickPosts); }
}
```

Droid Layout:

```
<MvxSpinner
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/limitSelect"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

Droid View:

```
...
var limitSelect = fragView.FindViewById<MvxSpinner>(Resource.Id.limitSelect);
...
...
set.Bind(limitSelect).For(x => x.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.LimitQuickPosts);
set.Bind(limitSelect).For(x => x.Selected).To(vm => vm.SelectedLimitQuickPosts);
```

While it appropriately binds `LimitQuickPosts` to the Spinner, and I can see all the available selections, I am left scratching my head on how Selected is not binding and what I must do for it to bind properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

```
set.Bind(limitSelect).For(x => x.Selected).To(vm => vm.SelectedLimitQuickPosts);
```

It should have been:

```
set.Bind(limitSelect).For(x => x.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedLimitQuickPosts);
```

Replace Selected with SelectedItem and it worked

Answer (score 1):

See this issue: [Issue binding to MVXSpinner after upgrading to Mvvmcross v4.0.0-beta3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718037/issue-binding-to-mvxspinner-after-upgrading-to-mvvmcross-v4-0-0-beta3)

You must call `MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories` from your Setup.cs's FillTargetFactories()